# Show taxonomy field in View

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have taxonomy called `Hardware Type` and it has field `Short Code`. Now content-type `Hardware's` has this taxonomy and I have a page which lists all `Hardware`. I want to show Hardware type's `short code` field but option is not available under fields.

What are the possible solutions to this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

NVM, I figured it out that relations can be added from `Advanced` menu, like below screenshot.

[image]